# Issue setting local heroku environment variables

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I'm using the following react buildpack with a heroku app:
https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack

I'm trying to set environment variables in the .env file when running the app locally, but the app is not picking them up.

Here's the contents of the .env file:

> $ cat .env
>  TEST=blap
>   JAWSDB_MARIA_URL=mysql://ubr638kkc74oaaky:p2ftrun8f5ap41e3@mcldisu5ppkm29wf.cbetxkdyhwsb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/kfo3ozwu8gjjl6lh

However there are other environment variables that are showing up in the app and I'm not sure where those are coming from (the expanded object is from console.log(process.env)):
[image]

There's a console message after running "heroku local web" that seems to indicate that the contents of .env got loaded:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the issue after reading the buildpack instructions more carefully. Create-react-app-buildpack does alter how local environment variables are handled (environment variables have to be prefixed with "env." in the app).

The pertinent part of the instructions can be found here:
https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack/blob/master/README.md#runtime-configuration

Comment: The link is dead... Moreover, this answer should be edited in order to contain the response, without the need of the link

Comment: Updated the link and also embedded the answer info in the SO thread.